# AS2 EDI communication, possibly Amazon VendorCentral specific

Tags: edi

I tried contacting Amazon support for this, but they have not replied since last week (unfortunately this is typical to not hear back for days, up to weeks). We currently do FTP for our EDI communication, but that is being discontinued at the end of this month, and we are trying to implement AS2, but we have more than one company internally, so as of now, we have 2 logins with Amazon, and each one has their own  FTP in which we pull and push EDI data back and forth.

Each trading partner with AS2 requires an identifier certificate (I believe is what it is called), and it costs a decent bit of money for them, but I need to know if we need only one, or two of them considering that we have two FTP's (VendorCentral accounts) currently, but it is the same trading partner. If anyone knows anything about AS2 in general and could shed some light on this, I would be extremely appreciative!

Thanks!

Dan

Comment: Most AS2 software allows you to create a self-signed user certificate.  They are "free" upon purchase.  It's a little different than going to Verisign for a SSL cert.  You would set up one AS2 connection and then route by ISA ID, because each partner should have a different ID.  But, alternatively, you can set up a separate listener for each partner.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do know about being able to upload your own certs, the thing is with our AS2 vendor we bought the software from for our iSeries AS400, they said it costs per "trading partner" for the Identifier, so I don't know if we need 2 of them or not in order to send to Amazon. I may just get one, test it and see if it will send to both accounts we have with them, and if not, then just get the other one.

Comment: Some AS2 software packages do charge by the "host" connection (Sterling, Cleo).  You might be okay if you let Amazon know the situation and have one end point for your two companies.  AS2 doesn't care about ISA ID, just AS2 ID.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have been waiting on Amazon for days now to reply back to this, but as usual. I got nothing yet.

Comment: You can use SFTP which is not being discontinued.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I realize this is an old post but since I've recently researched it for an [article](https://www.babelway.net/help/Help_Miscelleanous_CommonIntegrations_IntegrationPatterns_HowToAmazon.html) this may still help anyone else looking for this info.

You can think of AS2 like an email where the url is the domain name and the ID is the part before the @. 
AS2 requires:

- a URL
- a unique AS2 ID for that URL

The client certificate is used for security reasons but doesn't have to be unique per connection.

So you can stick to a single certificate for all your Amazon vendor central connections.

That being said, Amazon expects one connection per document type. This means you can't have purchase orders incoming through two different AS2 connections at the same time for example. So if your "sub-companies" are dealing with the same documents they will have to continue working with separate vendor central accounts.